# My brain is constipated, surely that's not correct

Tags: synonyms

I am unable to finish a project I am working, I just don't want to do it because the ideas to make it awesome are not flowing, I am not procrastinating, I want it completed, the only way I can describe it is that my brain is constipated. Surely there must be a better phrase.

Comment: Can't you just say *I'm stuck*?

Comment: No I don't think stuck is right

Comment: I'd leave awesome to George Bush and just aim for satisfactory. Use the time saved for Physiology 101.

Comment: You have *creative block* – a generalization of the older term *writer's block*.

Comment: "Constipated" works for me.  I don't know if there's any phrase "better" than that.  Saying that communicates a quite visceral and sensory image of your predicament.  Also, they're your words.  They're the words you landed on first.  There's something to be said for that. Don't second guess yourself so much.  Maybe that's the source of your brain constipation.  And saying "my brain is constipated" is creative and awesome, so if you just let that creativity come out instead of clenching down and questioning it so much, the bowels of your brain will move and ideas that are the sh*t will flow.